# C++: vector memory corruption when modifiying an object member from outside the copy constructor but not when modifying from within

Tags: c++, memory, vector, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

class a_class
{
public:

    int num_IN;

    a_class():num_IN(0){}
    a_class(a_class const & origin){/*Initialise();*/}   //if not called here, error occurs

    void Initialise(){num_IN =5;}
};

int main () 
{
    std::vector <a_class> the_vector;

    for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
    {
        the_vector.push_back(a_class());
        the_vector[q].Initialise();             
        assert(5 == the_vector[q].num_IN);      //no problem here
    }

    for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
        assert(the_vector[q].num_IN == 5);      //assertion fails
}
```

I don't understand the difference between calling this from outside vs. inside the CC. I also don't know why it should cause a problem in any case.

Comment: Apart fromt the answers below, you can also solve this with `vector<a_class> the_vector` **(30)**;. Still, Always make a good practice to have proper copy ctor.

Comment: To store objects in a vector, the objects must be copy constructible, which includes that the copy constructor must actually copy the object!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` may reallocate the buffer it uses if it's size outgrows it, in which case it has to copy the old elements over to the new buffer. If you don't have a proper copy constructor that copies `num_IN` over, the old value is lost.

Fix this by providing a proper copy constructor:

```
a_class(a_class const & origin) : num_IN(origin.num_IN) {}
```

In the code posted the copy constructor isn't even needed - if you don't provide one the compiler will generate a suitable one here.

Answer (score 3):

The `std::vector` class may have to reallocate the underlying dynamic array when you are repeatedly calling `push_back()` to append new elements. The usual strategy is for `std::vector` to increase the size of the underlying buffer by a factor, possibly a factor of `2`.

When this reallocation does occur, the copy constructor (or the move constructor if you've defined one and are using `c++0x`) is called to copy the vector's elements from the old buffer to the new one.

Your copy constructor is not actually copying properly, you should be assigning the `num_IN` parameter:

```
a_class(a_class const& src): num_IN(src.num_IN) {}
```

Typically, with `STL` containers, the data types stored should obey the "[rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)" in that the constructor, copy constructor, assignment operator and destructor all work together robustly.

With move semantics in `c++0x` I guess this should be extended to the "rule of five" in that you should also consider properly defined move constructors and move assignment operators.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of the `push_back`, your vector reallocates the memory in the first `for` loop whenever vector's `size` increases beyond its `capacity`. During this reallocation `vector` copies the objects already present in it by invoking the copy constructor . Since your copy constructor is not correct (You are not doing anything there), the initialized value is not carried over during reallocation.

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor isn't doing anything.  It should be saying num_IN = origin.num_IN;

Comment: I realize its not doing anything. I don't want `num_IN` to be set to `origin.num_IN`. I want to be able to set the value to something different from outside.

Comment: @ribram, It has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @iammilind Based on the other answers here, I would argue it has everything to do with the question.  @matt that is not what a copy constructor is.  It is required to make a copy of the source object or the world will break as you have seen.

Answer (score 1):

AHhh,

I can see what is happening.

In the first loop you are pushing back object to the vector, each time you push back the vector is resized and copy constructor is called on all the elements in the vector already. Since you have overwritten the copy constructor not to do anything, num_IN is left uninitialized.

to make it work. i would reenable to copy constructor to do member wise copy.

Alternatively.

i would resize the vector to the required size. This way, vector is not resized each time you add an  extra element

```
std::vector <a_class> the_vector;
the_vector.resize(30);

for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
{
    the_vector[q].Initialise();             
    assert(5 == the_vector[q].num_IN);      //no problem here
}

for(int q=0; q < 30; q++)
    assert(the_vector[q].num_IN == 5);      //assertion fails
```

Comment: Usually a buffer of a certain size is preallocated and, if outgrown, increased by a certain factor (usually two).